# "contract x" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail ganache

Tags: contract-deployment, ganache, gas-limit, truffle-deployment

i'm trying to deploy contracts on private network ganache using ganache application.
but it threw an error because of its big size:

```
"contract x" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail. Try:
   * Making your contract constructor more efficient
   * Setting the gas manually in your config or as a deployment parameter
   * Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js'
   * Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
     private network or test client (like ganache).
```

i tried to set a higher gas limit on ganache and changed it to 10000000 but still the same ptoblem.
[image]

truffle network config:

```
networks: {
     development: {
       host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
       port: 7545,
       network_id: "*"
     },
```

Comment: Well, are you sure the contract constructor code execution *can* succeed?

Comment: yes, when i remove some instructions (reduce the size of contract), it works, i think something about contract size that when i exceede it the block limit size reaches.

Comment: Can you share the contract code? In ethereum there is a limitation of 24kb per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve it by optimizing contract, comment out section in truffle-config.js file and set enable to true:

```
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
   optimizer: {
     enabled: true,
     runs: 200
   },
   evmVersion: "berlin"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think optimizing would really help in this case. Generally optimizing makes execution slightly cheaper at the expense of increasing the size of the code - if their issue is that their contract is too large, optimizing wont help, and will likely have the opposite effect